# How to display the priorities of roads on the route in different colors Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to display the priorities of roads on the route in different colors Google Maps
[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94TEn.jpg)

Comment: How do you know the "priority" of a segment of a road?

Comment: Related question: [how to draw a google maps waypoint with multi polylines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989237/how-to-draw-a-google-maps-waypoint-with-multi-polylines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question you need to divide your route on peaces with priorities (and set a color) for them
Did you look at [direction waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Yes, you understood correctly. I drew the route. Now I need to divide the route into pieces with the priorities.